# expected type-specifier before string constant

Tags: operator-keyword

I'd like to know what's wrong with this statement:

```
unsigned long long operator""_kHz(unsigned long long x) {
    return x * 1000;
}
```

I got the following error message.
error: expected type-specifier before string constant

Comment: which compiler ...make sure u have c++11 support turned on